# How to use "dump_pstats" properly to retrieve the sorted data of the "cProfile" into "txt" file?

Tags: python, cprofile, pstats

As the title indicate I have this issue of retrieving those information from dump_stats properly. Without further ado here is my simple code.

**Code**

```
import cProfile
import pstats

def fun_to_profile():
    ... code to be profilled ...

profiler = cProfile.Profile()

profiler.runcall(fun_to)profile)

stats.sort_stats('cumulative')

stats.print_stats()

stats.dump_stats("output.txt")
```

This is the simple code that I could found, and I really read multiple times the documentation.

**Problem**

My problem when I open the file "output.txt", even if it's empty or with non comprehended characters. So do I need to specify any extension of the file, or maybe the issue is with my compiler.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently working with `cProfile` is so easy and straight forwards. I figure the solution for the problem.

First of all we need to know that the more adequate file extension is `"file.dat"`. Then we need to read it and writing down in the desired files format like `text.txt`.

For that we need the following piece of code :

```
import cProfile
import pstats   
cProfile.run("fun_to_profile", "Out_put_profile.dat") # here we just run and save the output
with open("Profile_time.txt", "w") as f:
p = pstats.Stats("Out_put_profile.dat", stream=f)
p.sort_stats("time").print_stats() # here we sort our analysis by the time-spent
```

And just like this we will have a more materials for analyzing the code and in human readable format. Thanks for **IDG TECHtalk** for sharing the solution.
Link to the youtube video: https://youtu.be/dmnA3axZ3FY.